# Register Client Script is not working

Tags: application-pages

I want to redirect from application page within a model box to site root web url but for some reason it dont work i am adding this code

ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), String.Format("window.frameElement.navigateParent('{0}');", siteURL), true);

but it always takes me to page

http://www.hepod.com/sites/portal/subsite/http://www.hepod.com/sites/portal

thanks

Answer (score 0):

window.frameElement.navigateParent - works only for popup windows. Is your application page opens in popup? You can easily use window.location.href instead of this. Also it is necessary verify that siteURL has correct value.

Comment: it did not works uncaught TypeError: Property 'href' of object [object Location] is not a function

Comment: It's because you use it like a function. The correct using is window.location.href = siteURL;

Comment: still doesn't work :(

Comment: What the value of siteURL variable? Did you try Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "window.location.href = siteURL;", true);